# Alias Multiple 'AS' Statements - shorten amount of syntax - don't have to say "AS" for every alias?

Tags: mysql, sql, alias

When using Aliases with your select query like this:

```
SELECT u.col1 AS u_col1
    , u.col2 AS u_col2
    , u.col3 AS u_col3
    -- etc
    , u2.col1 AS u2_col1
    , u2.col2 AS u2_col2
    , u2.col3 AS u2_col3
etc.
```

---

Is there a way to shorten the amount of syntax? So you don't have to say '**AS**' for every  alias?

I thought maybe: `SELECT u.col1, u.col2 AS u_col1, u_col2`

But that didn't work.
Anyone know if it's possible?

Thanks all :)

Comment: You don't have to use `AS`. Just do `SELECT u.col1 u_col1, ...`

Comment: While omitting `AS` does remove a few characters, there is no shortcut for renaming column names .. read the error message for why the proposed syntax failed to work: `u_col2` comes from *where*? (Note: SQL Server allows duplicate column names in a result-set sent to a client that is not further used, but I am not sure how MySQL handles this.)

Comment: @EJP did you 'consider' not being a dic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

> The `AS` keyword is optional when aliasing a select_expr with an
>   identifier.

So simply do:

```
SELECT 
      u.col1 u_col1
    , u.col2 u_col2
    , u.col3 u_col3
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch @bernie - I appreciate you taking the time to explain that to me. Regards.